# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I run my pre-trained `text_encoder` like below to test my model on new queries and it completely runs

```
def find_matches(image_embeddings, queries, k=9, normalize=True):
   # Get the embedding for the query.
   query_embedding = text_encoder(tf.convert_to_tensor(queries))
   # Normalize the query and the image embeddings.
   if normalize:
     image_embeddings = tf.math.l2_normalize(image_embeddings, axis=1)
     query_embedding = tf.math.l2_normalize(query_embedding, axis=1)
   # Compute the dot product between the query and the image embeddings.
   dot_similarity = tf.matmul(query_embedding, image_embeddings, transpose_b=True)
   # Retrieve top k indices.
   results = tf.math.top_k(dot_similarity, k).indices.numpy()
   # Return matching image paths.
   return [[image_paths[idx] for idx in indices] for indices in results]
```

Output shapes of above

```
query_embedding shape is, (1, 128, 256)
dot_similarity shape is, (1, 128, 4795)
results shape is, (1, 128, 9)
```

and then when I run the below code to find matches for my desired query then it generates an error that `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

```
query = "a family standing next to the ocean on a sandy beach with a surf board"
matches = find_matches(image_embeddings, [query], normalize=True)[0]

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for i in range(9):
   ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
   plt.imshow(mpimg.imread(matches[i]))
   plt.axis("off")
```

error shows in this line

```
matches = find_matches(image_embeddings, [query], normalize=True)[0]
```

### whole code is in this [COLAB FILE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Jpw0Ym5mt2km-26VWdK8QuBY3Ei2szD0?usp=sharing).

Comment: Which line is giving the error? Try printing shape of array used in that line and also datatype of first element in that array.

Comment: This line is generating error `matches = find_matches(image_embeddings, [query], normalize=True)[0]`

Comment: Dig down deeper in error stacktrace and find which method call stack from function `find_matches()` is causing error. As mentioned above, analyse the array type used in that method call stack.

Comment: When I print `image_embeddings` shape it `(7470, 256)` and `dtype=float32`, and when I print query it's like this `['a family standing next to the ocean on a sandy beach with a surf board']`.

Comment: However my text encoder is trained on `sequence_output` which preprocess the sentence like this `['a', 'family', 'standing', 'next', 'to', 'the', 'ocean']` and then generate separate vectors for each word. so is my text encoder causing this issue which is above in this line `query_embedding = text_encoder(tf.convert_to_tensor(queries))`

Comment: Can you please add the whole error trace back? If I should guess I would say that your problem is that `idx` is not an intager, but I will need the full trace back for making sure.

Comment: Ok the code is little bit lengthy, I am sharing whole colab file, You read and if you have any question then ask me. I am available [CLICK THIS LINK](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Jpw0Ym5mt2km-26VWdK8QuBY3Ei2szD0?usp=sharing)